# How do i pipeline two program that share data through serial port in ubuntu linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, pipeline

I have two codes : Prog1 writes data to serial port Prog 2 reads data from serial port.
How do I run these programs simultaneously(pipeline) (on the same pc-loopback).
As far as i know:    prog1 | prog2  will connect the two programs but through stdin and stdout.
I want to connect them through the output of prog1 I've sent on serial port and receive it as input for prog2.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation

1. prog1 generates binary data and send it to the RS232C(USB-serial) port.
2. prog2 receives the binary data from RS232C(USB-serial) port.

It sounds to me that the prog1 output is already connected to the input of prog2,
without using pipe...

BTW, pipe is used for inter process communication using system memory.
pipe() system call returns two files descriptors, one channel with a
"read end" and the other channels with a "write end".
Then, you can communicate the data between two processes by using these descriptors respectively.
Please refer pipe(2) man page for the detail.

In order to do the loop back using serial port, I think you can not use pipe.
you have to use the descriptor by opening the serial port device file(/dev/ttyXX),
instead of the descriptor generated by pipe.
There are various way to achieve loopback.

1. RS232C TX and RX signal is physically connected.
   In this case, just open the device file of serial port (/dev/ttyxx).
   use read(), write() ioctl to exchange the data.
2. Use the hardware dependent loop back function.
   Some hardware can support loop back function for test purpose.
   you might be able to use this via ioctl(TIOCMBIS) with TIOCM_LOOP flag set.
   Refer tty_ioctl().
3. Using echo function of stty. Refer stty man page.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: serial port is /dev/ttyUSB0
How do i pipeline my programs through serial port and not through stdin stdout . Basically how do i change stdin to point to input from serial port.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you actually want to do.

Could you please explain more precisely why you need to connect the output of prog1 to input of prog2 ? What do you mean by pipeline ?
Can you please explain more what your prog1 and prog2 does ?

Comment: prog1 generates binary data, this data is to be send serially through RS232 port loopbacked and be received by prog2.
pipelining is i guess running more than one program simultaneously using command line.
for eg : prog1 | prog2|prog3 here o/p of prog1 acts as input of prog2 and so on. But these input outputs are stdin and stdout. How do i configure them to be i/p o/p from the serial port.